# in Dart ERROR : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in Flutter with Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with parsing firestore document fields to list of object. Here is my sample Json structure.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Nahit Fidancı",
    "email": "relativeaccount@gmail.com",
    "userType": "Relative"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hüseyin Özkoç",
    "email": "baba@gmail.com",
    "userType": "Relative"
  }
]
```

And codes that is trying to get a List of object from Json.

```js
  factory Patient.patientFromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(snapshot.data["relatives"].toString());

    RelativeList relativeList = RelativeList.fromJson(jsonResponse);

    return Patient(
      relatives: relativeList.relatives,
      todoList: List<String>.from(snapshot.data["todoList"]),
      location: snapshot.data["location"],
      userType: snapshot.data["userType"] == 'Patient'
          ? UserType.patient
          : UserType.relative,
      uid: snapshot.data["uid"],
      name: snapshot.data["name"],
      email: snapshot.data["email"],
      fileImage: snapshot.data["fileImage"],
      gender: snapshot.data["gender"] == 'Male' ? Gender.male : Gender.female,
      birthday: DateTime.parse(snapshot.data["birthday"]),
      registrationDate: DateTime.parse(snapshot.data["registrationDate"]),
      notification: snapshot.data["notification"],
    );
  }
```

Above code, there is no problem with getting `relatives` from Firestore. I stored decoded Json in to `jsonReponse` as type of `List<dynamic>`.
Problem start with calling `RelativeList.fromJson(jsonResponse)`.

```js
class RelativeList {
  final List<Relative> relatives;

  RelativeList(this.relatives);

  factory RelativeList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Relative> relatives =
        parsedJson.map((i) => Relative.fromJson(i)).toList();
    print(relatives);
    return RelativeList(relatives);
  }
}
```

Above code, when `List<Relative> relatives = parsedJson.map((i) => Relative.fromJson(i)).toList();` got executed it throws and error called `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`.
And this is how my `Relative.fromJson()` looks like.

```js
  factory Relative.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Relative(
      patients: List<String>.from(parsedJson["patients"]),
      faceModel: parsedJson["faceModel"],
      userType: parsedJson["userType"] == 'Patient'
          ? UserType.patient
          : UserType.relative,
      uid: parsedJson["uid"] ?? "",
      name: parsedJson["name"],
      email: parsedJson["email"],
      fileImage: parsedJson["fileImage"] ?? "",
      gender: (parsedJson["gender"] ?? 'Male') == 'Male'
          ? Gender.male
          : Gender.female,
      birthday: DateTime.parse(parsedJson["birthday"]) ??
          DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      registrationDate: DateTime.parse(parsedJson["registrationDate"]) ??
          DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      notification: parsedJson["notification"] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using null aware correctly. you have to check value is null or not when you are passing it ti any other constructor.

Use following Relative class.

```
class Relative {
  var patients;
  var faceModel;
  var userType;
  var uid;
  var name;
  var email;
  var fileImage;
  var notification;
  var registrationDate;
  var birthday;
  var gender;

  Relative(
      {this.name,
      this.birthday,
      this.email,
      this.faceModel,
      this.fileImage,
      this.gender,
      this.notification,
      this.patients,
      this.registrationDate,
      this.uid,
      this.userType});

  factory Relative.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Relative(
      patients: parsedJson["patients"] != null
          ? List<String>.from(parsedJson["patients"])
          : [],
      faceModel: parsedJson["faceModel"] ?? '',
      userType: parsedJson["userType"] == 'Patient'
          ? "UserType.patient"
          : "UserType.relative",
      uid: parsedJson["uid"] ?? "",
      name: parsedJson["name"] ?? '',
      email: parsedJson["email"] ?? '',
      fileImage: parsedJson["fileImage"] ?? "",
      gender: (parsedJson["gender"] ?? 'Male') == 'Male'
          ? "Gender.male"
          : "Gender.female",
      birthday: DateTime.parse(
          parsedJson["birthday"] ?? DateTime.now().toIso8601String()),
      registrationDate: DateTime.parse(
          parsedJson["registrationDate"] ?? DateTime.now().toIso8601String()),
      notification: parsedJson["notification"] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. After I try a couple of times, I solved it like your way. Thanks for your answer.